# Swift: Reverse order or progress bar

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have managed to get an animated progress bar to scroll across the top of the view over the course of 10 seconds. However I need to reverse it.

Here is the full code:

```
public enum BarPosition {
case Top
case TopStatus
case Bottom
}

class HBRViewController: UIViewController {

let kStandardBarHeight: CGFloat = 5

var progressBarPosition: BarPosition = BarPosition.Top
var progressBarColor: UIColor = UIColor.blueColor()

private var isProgressing: Bool = false
private var progressBar: UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

func startLoading() {
    if !isProgressing {
        self.progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.position(), 0, kStandardBarHeight)
        self.progressBar.backgroundColor = self.progressBarColor
        if self.progressBar.superview != self.view {
            self.view.addSubview(self.progressBar)
        }
        self.isProgressing = true
        let barWidth: CGFloat = self.view.frame.size.width * 1
        UIView.animateWithDuration(10, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.position(), barWidth, self.kStandardBarHeight)
        })
    }
}

func finishLoading() {
    if isProgressing {
        let projectileFrame = self.progressBar.layer.presentationLayer()!.frame
        self.progressBar.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.progressBar.frame = projectileFrame
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.progressBar.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.position(), self.view.frame.size.width, self.kStandardBarHeight)
        }) { (Bool) -> Void in
            self.hideProgressBar()
        }
    }
}

private func hideProgressBar() {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: { () -> Void in
        switch self.progressBarPosition {
        case .Top, .TopStatus:
            self.progressBar.frame.size.height = 0
        case .Bottom:
            self.progressBar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.progressBar.frame))
        }
    }) { (Bool) -> Void in
        self.progressBar.removeFromSuperview()
        self.progressBar.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
        self.isProgressing = false
    }
}

func position() -> CGFloat {
    switch self.progressBarPosition {
    case .TopStatus:
        if (self.navigationController != nil) {
            return CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame)
        } else {
            return CGRectGetMaxY(UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame)
        }
    case .Top:
        if (self.navigationController != nil) {
            return CGRectGetMaxY(self.navigationController!.navigationBar.frame)
        } else {
            return 0.0 as CGFloat
        }
    case .Bottom:
        return self.view.frame.size.height - kStandardBarHeight
    }
}

}
```

Can someome tell me how to get the bar to show across the full width of the screen and then shrink in 10 seconds?

Comment: So you're using https://github.com/Ryce/HBRProgressBar but you don't know _how_ to use it?

Comment: Is it on github? I followed a tutorial - maybe it was the same guy